# Error: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

mi firts error when i run the code is:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I try with numpy 1.11.0 install but it doesn't work. If y change to int() the are a new error:

This is the code:

```
# Load airfoil from file
def airfoil_from_file(fname, n=256):
    dat = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1)
    eps=1e-8

    num1 = round(dat[0,0])
    num2 = round(dat[0,1])

    if num1>1: 
        xy = zeros((num1+num2-1,2))
        xy[:num1,:] = dat[1:1+num1,:][::-1,:]
        xy[num1:,:] = dat[2+num1:,:]
    else:
        xy=dat.copy()
```

First error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute.py", line 18, in <module>
    rx, ry = airfoil_from_file('clarky.dat', n=128)
  File "/home/david/Descargas/L04PanelMethod/geometry.py", line 29, in airfoil_from_file
    xy = zeros((num1+num2-1,2))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

If i change to int():

```
def airfoil_from_file(fname, n=256):
    dat = int(np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1))
    eps=1e-8
```

New error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compute.py", line 18, in <module>
    rx, ry = airfoil_from_file('clarky.dat', n=128)
  File "/home/david/Descargas/L04PanelMethod/geometry.py", line 22, in airfoil_from_file
    dat = int(np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=1))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `xy = zeros((num1+num2-1,2))` to `xy = zeros((int(num1+num2)-1,2))` in your original code.

rounding only rounds, but it does not convert to int.

```
num1 = round(dat[0,0])

num2 = round(dat[0,1])
```

Rounds to nearest float in your case, e.g. round(12.4) = 12.0.

Comment: thanks i change it but now i have a new error:  


xy[:num1,:] = dat[1:1+num1,:][::-1,:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: @davidnuñezfernandez You have exactly the same error in a different place. Why not try the same solution?